# How do I parameterize flyway.properties to reference the user's home directory?

Tags: flyway

I'm trying to check into vcs a flyway.properties file that will work on all of the developers' machines. I need to parameterize flyway.properties, and can't figure out how. Maybe it isn't supported; please let me know.

Here are two properties I'm trying to set. You can see I'm using the Java user.home system property in an attempt to reference the user's home directory.

```
flyway.locations=filesystem:${user.home}/workspace/project-clone/sql
flyway.jarDir=${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.3-1101-jdbc41
```

Flyway seems to want sql and jars in its install directory, but that's not project specific, and I want my colleagues to like the tool, so please help me figure out how to make it one-liner easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently isn't supported directly. You can however use symlinks to achieve this. If this doesn't satisfy your needs, please file a feature request in the issue tracker.